# Create an instance of a C# class from inside XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a working application that has been written in C#, and I now want to extend that application to allow the user to switch between viewing the application, and viewing a built in web browser (inside the same application window).

I also have a separate working web browser, that has also been written in C#.

I have just added the functionality to the original application to include 'tabbed' displays, where the original application will be displayed on the first tab, and a built in web browser on the second tab.

The 'tabbed' displays for the application have been created using `XAML` markup in Visual Studio. I now want to add an instance of the Web browser that has also been written in C# to the second tab that I have created in the XAML markup.

It would be something like:

```
<TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Browser">
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Call/ instantiate the browser here -->
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

But I have no idea how I call/ create an instance of the browser from within the XAML markup...

The browser has been created using C#:

```
namespace Agent
{
    public partial class Browser : Form
    {
        public Browser()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me how a create an instance of `Browser` inside the ` of the XAML markup?

**Edit**

Ok, so I have edited my XAML markup as recommended in the answer that's been suggested- I now have:

```
<Window ...
  xmlns:Agent="clr-namespace:Agent"
  ...>
    <Grid>
        ...
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="R">
                <StackPanel>
                    ...
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Browser">
                <Agent:Browser x:Name="Browser" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have also updated my `Browser.cs` class, so that it is now extending `UserControl`, rather than `Form`:

```
public partial class Browser : UserControl{
```

However, I am getting a compile error on the line:

```
<Agent:Browser x:Name="Browser" />
```

which says:

> The name "Browser" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Agent".

But clearly `Browser` does exist in `Agent`, as shown by the code I've included here... In fact, when typing the line `<Agent:Browser x:Name="Browser />`, when I typed the `:`, `Browser` was one of the options that came up in the autocomplete menu...

What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't the compiler think that `Browser` exists inside `Agent`?

Comment: You are mixing (old and ugly, my personal opinion) `WinForms` with beautiful `WPF`. For the `WinForms` you need `<WindowsFormsHost />` element. Good luck, you are going to need it.

Comment: I'm new to `WPF`, and haven't used `WinForms` before either... what's the difference? What should I be doing?

Comment: Could you update your Question with the new browser deriving from UC and show us how exactly you are using it in your XAML?

Comment: Hi, I've just updated my question to show how I've tried doing what was suggested in the answer below, and how that isn't working for me at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to instantiating any object in XAML is to make sure the namespace is declared.  You can provide any XML prefix and assign it to your CLR namespace ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.100).aspx)) and it will act like a `using` statement.  For example:

```
<TabControl xmlns:agent="clr-namespace:Agent">
    <TabItem Header="Browser">
        <StackPanel>
            <agent:Browser/>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

NOTE: your object has to extend `UIElement` (or one of its children) for it to work in a XAML tree.  If your control is a WinForms control you either need to find the equivalent XAML control or wrap it in a `WindowsFormsHost` ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761(v=vs.100).aspx)).

---

**WPF vs. WinForms**

The purpose of this section is to help recognize which platform code is by namespace, as well as some of the trade-offs.  I've used both and can say from experience that they each have good points and... not so good points.

- WinForms classes live in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, and are available by referencing the System.Windows.Forms.dll assembly.
- WPF classes live in the `System.Windows` and `System.Windows.Controls` namespaces, and are available by referencing a set of DLLs
- WinForms rendering is *immediate*.  That means you are working against bitmaps and you are responsible for clearing and redrawing stuff yourself (usually you can just call Invalidate()).  If you do heavy image bit manipulation, WinForms is easier to work with.
- WPF rendering is *declarative*.  That means more work is offloaded to your GPU and you just tell it how to draw stuff.  You can also use GPU render shaders for special effects.  WPF has a nicer look out of the box, but it has a reputation for making easy things difficult but impossible things possible.
- WinForms is easier to learn, but has a dated look out of the box.
- WPF is built around data binding, enabling the UI to update in response to property values automatically.  It's also able to be completely restyled, although that is quite an undertaking.

If you are just getting started, I'd go ahead and bite the bullet to start the heavier learning curve for WPF.  It will provide a basic understanding that transfers to other platforms like Windows Store apps, etc.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I've given what you suggested a go, but I'm getting a compile error in the XAML, which says: `The namespace prefix "Agent" is not defined.`... The compile error is highlighting the line `<agent:Browser />`.

Comment: My `Browser` class extends `Form`, which I guess is what you're saying about needing to find the equivalent XAML control?

Comment: The namespaces are case sensitive, so make sure the capitalization is correct.  And yes, extending `Form` from the WinForms API isn't going to work.  The equivalent for WPF would be the `UserControl` base class.  You really need to decide which platform you are building for and only use that platform.

Comment: Ok, so my `Browser` class now extends `UserControl` rather than `Form` and declares its namespace with `namespace Agent{`... Then, in the XAML markup, the `<TabControl>` tag is opened with `<TabControl xmlns:agent="clr-namespace:Agent"></TabControl>`, and I'm performing the call to `<agent:Browser />` inside `<StackPanel></StackPanel>` as you mentioned in your answer. However, that line is giving me a compile error which says: `The name "Browser" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Agent"... Is there something else I need to do here, to ensure that it can see the browser?

Comment: I'm now getting a compile error that says: `A value of type 'Browser' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'... any ideas?

Comment: I think that if I want to be able to use my existing browser (`Browser.cs`) from inside the XAML file, I will need to create/ write the XAML for my browser class (i.e. `Browser.xaml` & `Browser.xaml.cs`). How would I do this?

Comment: Visual Studio has several options for "Add Item".  You would simply choose "User Control" and you will have a `Browser.xaml` and `Browser.xaml.cs` that extents `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`.  A `UserControl` is designed to be something you embed inside XAML, whether it's for a `Window` or for another `UserControl`.

Comment: I think the issue was that I was missing a reference to the `namespace` that the browser class belonged to when trying to instantiate it in the C# function that was being called by the `XAML`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to place that tag inside of your `UserControl` opening tag like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="View.testControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:Agent="clr-namespace:Agent">
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="R">
        <StackPanel>
            ...
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Browser">
        <Agent:Browser x:Name="Browser" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

**EDIT**
From what you told me in the comments you will need to create a `Custom Control` in your WPF project. To do that you need to:

1. Right Click your Project;
2. Select Add New Item;
3. From Installed (which is in the left column) select `WPF`;
4. From the list in the middle column select `Custom Control`;

Now you can create that control in your XAML with `xmlns` attribute.
[Here is a great example from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc295235.aspx) on how to create custom controls

Comment: I don't currently have a `<UserControl></UserControl>` tag... I'm guessing I need to include that somewhere? Where would I nest it? The structure of my XML is currently: `<Window ...><Grid><Menu></Menu><TabControl><TabItem...><StackPanel>....</StackPanel></TabItem><TabItem...></TabItem></TabControl></Grid></Window>` and I'm trying to nest the browser inside the second `<TabItem></TabItem>` tags.

Comment: The `xmlns:Agent="clr-namespace:Agent"` is inside my `<Window>...</Window>` tag- which I guess would be the `UserControl` opening tag you mean?

Comment: @someone2088 yes you need to replace <UserControl with <WIndow

Comment: So that's what I already have- I've updated the code displayed in my OP to show the full structure of my `XAML` file.

Comment: Do I need to somehow include/ use the `Browser.cs` class inside the XAML, similar to how I'm including/ using the namespace `Agent`?

Comment: @someone2088 where is your Browser.cs located? Is it in the same project as your Window or is it in a separate assembly, like class Library? if it is in a separate project you need to include the assembly name as well in your xaml. like so: `xmlns:Agent="clr-namespace:Agent;assembly=Agent"`

Comment: Yes, `Browser.cs` is in the same project as `Window.xaml`... The project solution is `Agent` (which is used as the `namespace`), and inside that, I have both my `Window.xaml` file, and my `Browser.cs` file... They are both directly inside the project solution (i.e. not nested on different levels/ in sub folder, etc)

Comment: I've had a look at some other examples, and it seem that I  might need a `.xaml` file for my browser (i.e. `browser.xaml` & `browser.xaml.cs`), in order to be able to use it... I could then declare `<Window x:Class="Agent.Browser"` at the top of the browser XML, which would mean it belonged to the `Agent` namespace. How would I write the XAML markup for my existing C# browser?

Comment: Thanks for the update to your answer- I already have the `Browser.cs` class, which is the custom control that I want to embed inside the main window of my project- how do I ensure that I can reference/ use this from within the XML? The namespace for my project is `Agent`, so when I type `<Agent:` into the XAML file, I'm expecting the list of autocomplete options to include `Browser`, but it doesn't at the moment... even though `Browser.cs` is defined in the `Agent` namespace... how can I ensure that `Browser` is visible/ usable inside the XAML file for my main window?

Comment: @someone2088 Have you read the link that is included in the update? That basically explains how to do that. However sometimes IntelliSense will fail, so I would try to `Clean` the solution and the `Rebuild` it, that sometimes helps.

Comment: Yes, I read the link in the update- thanks. But it seems that this is for adding a control to the form (i.e. adding a button or something that will allow you to manipulate the form, or a part of it). What I am looking to do, is embed a (more or less) fully functional web browser inside my WPF application, so that I can display a particular website to the user from inside my application, and allow them to interact with that website as if they were viewing it from a 'normal' web browser, such as Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: When I add the line: `<Agent:Browser x:Name="WebBrowser" />` to my XAML file, I get a compile error on that line, which says `A value of type 'Browser' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'`

Comment: `Browser` is defined within the namespace `Agent`, so I would expect the XAML to be able to see/ reference `Browser`, given that I have included the namespace `Agent`...?

Comment: @someone2088 have you tried deriving from `Control` rather than `UserControl`?

Comment: I'm not actually deriving from either at the moment- my `mainWindow.xaml.xs` class is inheriting from `Window`, i.e. `public partial class MainWindow : Window`... does that make a difference?

Comment: @someone2088 Your Browser should derive from `Control` then the XAML will not complain about the type of the control, what I mean it will stop that error "Cannot add to UICollection". MainWindow.xaml.cs should derive from Window class, so that's fine. However I don't understand why this is not picking up for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111433/discussion-between-someone2088-and-xamlmax).